# How to correctly apply color filter to a View?

Tags: java, android

I want to create a color filter that can change view colors to green and white.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
float[] mx = {
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 255
        };

paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(mx));
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, paint);
```

Here is the code I'm using. Everything works well but my white color becomes greenish but I want I to remain white.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
float[] mx = {
                 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
                 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 255
        };
```